# Which database storage option in Azure should I consider for managing configuration data?

Tags: database, api, cloud-storage, azure

I have a UI which should fetch data from an API that access a database for selecting one of the entries.

Specifications:-

1. The number of entries in the database will be less than 100.
2. The structure of the database can change.
3. The API will be called once everytime the user logs in.
4. Should be feasible(cost).

With respect to these specification please help me choose a database storage option from Azure.